# Record mode in vim across multiple files

Tags: vim, edit

Suppose I open multiple files in gvim like:

```
gvim file1 file2 file3
```

Suppose I made a set of changes in `file1` and I want to record those changes and run them across all the other opened files. Can I do that with the record mode available in gvim?

Answer (score 0):

You can't record something that already happened but you can play an existing recording (saved in register `q` for the sake of demenstration) on every buffer in the buffer list with:

```
:bufdo @q
```

If what you want to repeat in other buffers is a substitution, you can do:

```
:bufdo g&
```

If it's an Ex command:

```
:bufdo @:
```